# How to disable Gmail antispam

Tags: gmail

I can't find any working trick for disabling Gmail antispam system. Some time ago it was possible to create filter for pulling all messages to Inbox. But nowadays in Filter settings I can't find such option.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want anything sent to the spam folder, set up a filter to catch all incoming mail (`From: *`) and in the actions, check the `Never send it to Spam` checkbox.